# Finding all users who joined this year in postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a date column for visitors, what I want to query is the all visitors whose 1st visit is this year. In pseudo code this is:

```
select visitorid, min(date_part('year', visitdate)) as first_visit 
where first_visit = date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE);
```

This results in error(s) in pgadmin editor

How can I get the required results????

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select visitorid
from t
group by visitorid
having min(visitdate) >= date_trunc('year', now());
```

Comment: Nice one!  Many thanks for the quick reply  @Gordon Linoff